# Putting element names in a list "[]" with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, expression

I want to put all input element names of a specific parent to a list with Jquery.

```
<form id="got">
  <input name="jon">
  <input name="oberyn">
  <input name="tyrion">
</form>

var inputs = ["jon", "oberyn", "tyrion"];
```

So i can manipulate them with forEach.

How can i do that?

Comment: `$('input', $('#got'))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `.map` method.

```
var inputs = $('#got').find('input').map(function() {
  return $(this).attr('name');
}).get();
```

Comment: FWIW, `name` is a reflected property. So `$(this).attr("name")` is a really long-winded way to write `this.name`.

Answer (score 1):

Try using arrays - jQuery **[.each().](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)**

**[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SSW85/)**

```
var arr = [];
$('#got input').each(function(){
    arr.push($(this).prop('name'));       //a simple way : arr.push(this.name);
    console.log(arr); 
});
```

Comment: FWIW, `name` is a reflected property. So `$(this).prop("name")` is a really long-winded way to write `this.name`.